# Iterating over a 2D list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to collect the result of a function in a data structure. In java the loop looks like the following code:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = func(var1, var2, ...);
   }
}
```

How can I do that in *Mathematica*? What kind of data structure shuold I use? `func` makes some calculations on an image, I have to collect the results and after that I have to save it as another image. I know that `func` works.

I welcome any help. I'm new to Mathematica, I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Although there are many possibilities, `Table` probably is best.

Comment: Something like: `arr = Table[function[i, j], {i, 0, arrLength - 1}, {j, 0, arrLength - 1}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some options that generate the same output, assuming you have set `arrLength`:

As suggested by bill s in comments, and probably the easiest to understand:

```
arr = Table[
 function[i, j], {i, 0, arrLength - 1}, {j, 0, arrLength - 1}]
```

Using `Array` instead - note the third argument to get the arguments starting at zero.

```
arr2 = Array[function, {arrLength, arrLength}, {0, 0}]
```

You might not need a matrix, which is what the data structure implies. Here is a more complex example that, without the use of `Partition`, would have given a single vector of all the `function` elements.

```
Partition[
  Apply[function, Tuples[Range[0, arrLength - 1], 2], {1}], arrLength]
```

And my favorite - don't forget `Outer`:

```
Outer[function, Range[0, arrLength - 1], Range[0, arrLength - 1]]
```

The advantages of the `Array` and `Outer` formulations is that you don't have to specify any local iterator variables. For more complex cases this might make your code easier to follow.

To answer the question of what data structure to use, it might be helpful to read some of the introductory material on the language on the Wolfram web site. All of the above simply output lists of lists of `function[i,j]` elements (which would be real numbers if `function` was defined. In your specific case, the data is essentially a matrix, but please understand that the `List` expression in Mathematica is much more general than that. It can handle ragged lists and lists of any nested depth.

This is an example of the way Mathematica is very unlike languages such as Java. As well as not needing a nested loop to generate a simple matrix of numbers (I mean, really? Other languages still require this? I am *so* spoiled as a Mathematica user), the resulting matrix doesn't care if it contains real numbers, exact numbers, strings, symbolic expressions, pictures, sounds or whatever.

Comment: It works. Many thanks